# PHP AJAX pagination load items into multiple containers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I would like to create a simple "load more" button but I have a three column design which makes it a little comlicated because I only want to load the items into their parent element. I used infinite ajax scroll on other sites but in this case it doesn't work or it works if I set the items to load to the parent element.

my html layout looks like this:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="firstcol column">
    <article class="item">Content</article>
    <article class="item">Content</article>
    <article class="item">Content</article>
  </div>
  <div class="secondcol column">
    <article class="item">Content</article>
    <article class="item">Content</article>
    <article class="item">Content</article>
  </div>
  <div class="thirdcol column">
    <article class="item">Content</article>
    <article class="item">Content</article>
    <article class="item">Content</article>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="padination">
  <a class="next" href="http://example.com/?start=10">load more</a>
</div>
```

So, if its possible I want to load only the  elements into its appropriate column.
Is there a solution for this or do I need to load the column divs and figure out a way with css to make it look nice?
Oh almost forgot if I don't have any JS/AJAX than the load more link works like any other php-mysql pagination (for example like on a joomla blog layout) and the data returned and printed is the same as the html code above.

I hope my question is clear.

Comment: Seems like it would be possible. But without more information about the structure of the data you are getting back, I can't make any specific suggestions.

Comment: The data is the same as the html code I posted, thats why I wrote that the pagination works like a joomla one. Or did you mean a js console.log data?

Comment: What determines what an appropriate column is for an element? It is not really clear to me what you are trying to do.  Perhaps if you show before and after state of your DOM that would help.

Answer (score 0):

If your AJAX call is returning HTML, you can set that into a jQuery object then retrieve specific parts of it. This is untested, but in principle it should work:

```
"success" : function(data) {
    //add articles from first col of return html
    var $html = $(data);
    $html.find("div.firstcol article").appendTo("div#container div.firstcol");
    $html.find("div.secondcol article").appendTo("div#container div.secondcol");
    $html.find("div.thirdcol article").appendTo("div#container div.thirdcol");
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement your solution to Infinite Ajax Scroll but when I console.log the data/items than it returns an object like this `Object[div.firstcol, div.secondcol, div.thirdcol]` and the if I console.log the `find(div.firstcol article)` than it returns an empty object

Comment: Is the AJAX call returning JSON or HTML?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure, the documantation says that 'data' should return a string and 'items' should return an array, but if i log 'data' than it returns something like this:`Object[<TextNode textContent="\n\n\n">, meta, <TextNode textContent="\n">, meta,....footer#footer, <TextNode textContent="\n">, <TextNode textContent="\n">, script, <TextNode textContent="\n\n">]`

Comment: Just for a test, if you create a textarea and have the success function set the value of it to the return value, does it give you something like [Object], or actual HTML?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. But I did a print_scrn from `console.log($html.find("div.firstcol"))` maybe it helps [link to the pic](http://hofehermosoly.eu/images/consolelog.jpg)

Comment: As I wrote before I'm trying to implement this to Infinite Ajax Scroll which is a jquery plugin [link](http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/docs/overview.html) which has two event before it appends the data to html one is 'loaded' and the other is 'render'